# UNION SELECT CONCAT works differently between MariaDB / MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, concatenation

I've recently migrated an application from MySQL 5.5 to MariaDB 10.3.
Part of the application is an event calendar where users can put in their own events with details like address, town etc.

I noticed that one of the queries that run this software don't work with MariaDB anymore, although the syntax should still be fine.

I've tried to get back to MySQL 5.5 and the query works again.
I also ran the query in phpMyadmin on MariaDB 10.3 and it shows the same results, but ends with the error:

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual for
>   the right syntax to use near 'UNION SELECT CONCAT(title_clang_1,' -
>   ',street,' ',zip,' ',district,' ', town,' in line 1

This is the query:

```
SELECT
  'choose' label,
  '' id
FROM
  table_events
LIMIT
  1
UNION
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    title_clang_1,
    ' - ',
    street,
    ' ',
    zip,
    ' ',
    district,
    ' ',
    town,
    ' ',
    additional
  ) label,
  id
FROM
  table_events
WHERE
  offline IS NULL || offline = '|0|'
```

The table "table_events" contains all the columns listed here: id, title_clang_1, street, zip, district, town, additional - and more that are not relevant for this query.

I expect an output of all events that have the offline field filled with zero or NULL, instead I get a syntax error.

Comment: ' offline IS NULL || offline = '|0|''  I'm not convinced this is mysql or mariadb syntax, what's it supposed to do?

Comment: @P.Salmon `||` (alternative to `OR`) is accepted by MySQL and MariaDB both: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/or/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya Thanks I wasn't aware of that , still think or isn;t much of an overhead over ||

Comment: The error I get in mariadb Server version: 10.1.14-MariaDB is ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UNION and LIMIT

Comment: Not to mention using `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` to select the "first" record is **meaningless** as defined by the ANSI/ISO SQL standards tables/resultsets are **orderless** .. The result of that query will be non deterministic (random) to get a pure 100% deterministic (fixed) always you would atleast have to add a column in the `ORDER BY` clause with a primary or unique key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this query of yours will not work in MySQL as well (in the newer versions atleast). [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) clearly states:

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT

You need to use parentheses around your individual `SELECT` query blocks, as you are using `LIMIT` in your first query:

```
(
SELECT
  'choose' label,
  '' id
FROM
  table_events
LIMIT
  1
)
UNION
(
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    title_clang_1,
    ' - ',
    street,
    ' ',
    zip,
    ' ',
    district,
    ' ',
    town,
    ' ',
    additional
  ) label,
  id
FROM
  table_events
WHERE
  offline IS NULL || offline = '|0|'
)
```

Comment: Not to mention using `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` to select the "first" record is **meaningless** as defined by the ANSI/ISO SQL standards tables/resultsets are **orderless** .. The result of that query will be non deterministic (random) to get a pure 100% deterministic (fixed) always you would atleast have to add a column in the `ORDER BY` clause with a primary or unique key.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are absolutely right. Although OP is misusing (unnecessarily) `SELECT` query to generate constant text as column headers (for his table, I guess!). It seems that `UNION` is absolutely not needed in his usecase. And he could simply generate these column headers in the application code instead.

Comment: *"he could simply generate these column headers in the application code instead."* Agree but  `(
SELECT
  'choose' label,
  '' id
FROM
  table_events
LIMIT
  1
)` should/could have been simply `(
SELECT
  'choose' label,
  '' id
FROM
  DUAL
)` then